# Italic roman page numbering in frontmatter

Tags: memoir, page-numbering, italic, front-matter

I'm using the `memoir` documentclass, and I would like to have `roman` page numbering, in the `front matter`, in `italic`. Does anyone know how to do it or can reference me something to read?

P.S. I am looking *just* for italicising the `roman` page numbering of the preface and *not* for patching multiple things (I'd like to add only what I understand, and since I am a newby, I understand just a little)

Comment: Which page style are you using?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Gonzalo I'm using the `article` `oneside`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to make this happen is to redefine `\thepage` with `\textit{...}` command inside `\frontmatter` and reset to upright after `\mainmatter` command. See below example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
%% Making italic page number in frontmatter
\def\thepage{\textit{\roman{page}}}

\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum

\mainmatter
%% Making upright page number in mainmatter
\def\thepage{\arabic{page}}

\chapter{One}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, it has been even easier. I just needed to add `\def\thepage{\textit{\roman{page}}}` right after the `\frontmatter`. That is all I wanted. Thank you indeed.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use the new macro `\ThePage` in the page style definitions.
In the `\frontmatter` part, it expands to `\textit{\thepage}`, after `\mainmatter` it expands to `\thepage`.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand*{\FrontMatterThePageFont}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand*{\MainMatterThePageFont}[1]{#1}
\newcommand*{\ThePage}{%
  \MainMatterThePageFont{\thepage}%
}

\makeatletter

% \frontmatter
\addtodef*{\@memfront}{}{%
  \pagenumbering{Roman}%
  \renewcommand*{\ThePage}{%
    \FrontMatterThePageFont{\thepage}%
  }%
}

% \mainmatter
\addtodef*{\@memmain}{}{%
  \renewcommand*{\ThePage}{%
    \MainMatterThePageFont{\thepage}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{\ThePage}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\ThePage}{}
\makeevenhead{simple}{\ThePage}{}{}
\makeoddhead{simple}{}{}{\ThePage}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\ThePage}{}{\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\slshape\rightmark}{}{\ThePage}
\makeevenhead{myheadings}{\ThePage}{}{\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{myheadings}{\slshape\rightmark}{}{\ThePage}
\makeevenfoot{ruled}{\ThePage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{ruled}{}{}{\ThePage}
\makeevenfoot{Ruled}{\ThePage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{Ruled}{}{}{\ThePage}
% ...

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Experiments}
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- I have patched `\@memfront` and `\@memmain` instead of `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. because of the star forms that class `memoir` provides (the star
  forms do not change the page numbering).
- I have added a list that changes `\thepage` to `\ThePage` for some predefined page styles. In your own page style definitions, just use `\ThePage` instead of `\thepage`.

Comment: Ehm.. Thank you, but.. isn't there an easier solution? I mean, I was simply looking for having the number italised.. and not patching LaTeX.. Can I use just part of your code? It's quite complicated, and therefore I cannot tell if it is possible to extract just what I need (the `italicised` part). Could you help?