# Frontmatter page count problem in memoir package

Tags: memoir, page-numbering

I am using `memoir` class for preparing a document. Here raises a problem with page numbering. For problem demonstration, consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\centering Author Intro}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{\centering Review committee}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{\centering Preface}
\lipsum[1-5]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Sec1}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter{Chap2}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Sec1}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter{Chap3}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Sec1}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter{Chap4}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Sec1}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

I want the page numbers in the `frontmatter` not to show in header or footer. But they should continue the page counting. The page counter should start from the very beginning of the document. Now, it starts from 1 in `\mainmatter`excluding `\frontmatter`. Thats means it resets. I don't want that.

I restated my query:

The `\mainmatter` page numbers should consider the `\frontmatter` pages. It should not be reset to 0/1. But the `\frontmatter` pages should not show any numbering, should be empty.

Thanks.

Note : I find a partial solution here: [Italic roman page numbering in frontmatter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124840/italic-roman-page-numbering-in-frontmatter)
Though it is not working accurately for me.

Comment: First of you should not define `\thepage` to nothing, use the `empty` page style. `\mainmatter` always resets the page counter to 0 because `\frontmatter` typesets it in roman numerals. Use `\mainmatter*` to not have this reset. Additionally I would not use `\chapter{\centering Preface}` as it gives an inconsistent design.

Comment: @daleif What is a good solution for `\chapter{\centering Preface}`?

Comment: @daleif is this `\def\thepage{\empty}`?

Comment: @daleif `\mainmatter*` removes the page number.

Comment: Yes because you deleted the posibility of even printing the page number by that redefintiion. BTW: normal users should never use `\def`. Pagestyles are issues using `\pagestyle{name}` (affect the next page onward) and `\thispagestyle{name}` onl;y currnet page.

Comment: Perhaps you should start over with your question and instead state what your goal is? It is not clear what should happen to page numbers for frontmatter elements in relation to the TOC.

Comment: @daleif Frontmatter includes TOC, isn't it? I want the whole `\frontmatter` should not have any page numbering. But the pages should be counted. The page numbering in main matter should be shown including the page counts of frontmatter, *not from 1*. Is it clear?

Comment: Please update the question such that the requirement is clear. Again this is not clear: `Frontmatter includes TOC, isn't it?` Again I suggest, rewriting the entire question, keep the example but remove the redefintiion of `\thepage` as that is not a good solution, a lot of things will break as soon as you add `hyperref`.

Comment: @daleif I have updated my question.

Comment: You haven't stated what needs to happen to pages numbers of the frontmatter elements when listed in the TOC. Should `Preface` have a page number in the TOC?

Comment: No, not actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to my interpretation of your requirements.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

% hooks to be executed inside the toc
\cftinsertcode{A}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\cftinsertcode{B}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}

\makechapterstyle{centerstyle}{%
  % default style plus
  \renewcommand*\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\centering}
}


\begin{document}

% no roman nums
\frontmatter*

% add hook to toc
\cftinserthook{toc}{A}
% no page numbers
\pagestyle{empty}
% no page numbers on chapter pages
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}
\chapterstyle{centerstyle}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Author Intro}
\kant[1-2]
\chapter{Review committee}
\kant[1-2]
\chapter{Preface}
\kant[1-5]


% mainmatter, don't touch numbering
\mainmatter*

% bring back the normal page style
\pagestyle{headings}
% bring back the normal chapter page style
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plain}
% add another hook, to revert the first one
\cftinserthook{toc}{B}

\chapterstyle{default}


\chapter{Intro}
\kant[3]
\section{Sec1}
\kant[3-9]
\chapter{Chap2}
\kant[3]
\section{Sec1}
\kant[3-8]
\chapter{Chap3}
\kant[3]
\section{Sec1}
\kant[3-7]
\chapter{Chap4}
\kant[3]
\section{Sec1}
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```